# Proving divisibility of expression using induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction

**Question:**

**Part a:**

Prove that for any $ b\in \Bbb N,$ if $ 2^{3b -1} + 5 . 3^{b}$ is divisible by $ 11$, then $ 2^{3(b+2) -1} + 5 . 3^{b+2}$ is divisible by $11$.

**Part b:**

Is statement 1 or statement 2 true? Explain answer.

1. For any odd number $a\in \Bbb N $, $ 2^{3a -1} + 5 . 3^{a}$ is divisible by $ 11$
2. For any even number $a\in \Bbb N $, $ 2^{3a -1} + 5 . 3^{a}$ is divisible by $ 11$

**My attempt:**

**Part a:**

I am not sure what the base case should be.

Induction hypothesis: Assume $ 2^{3k -1} + 5 . 3^{k}$ is divisible by $ 11$, for some $k$ natural number.

I am not sure how to prove true for $ 2^{3(k+2) -1} + 5 . 3^{k+2}$.

**Part b:**

Would statement 2 be correct since the expression is divisible by $11$ when $ a=2$

Comment: For part a, note that there is no "base case" to prove. You also don't need to use a new variable $k$; you can just use $b$.

Comment: So I don't need an induction hypothesis?

Comment: For part b, $a=1$ is a counter example, while $a=2$ is just an example. Both of them could be wrong

Comment: How do I determine which statement is true in part b?

Comment: @George the answer below uses $ b = 2$ to show its true for all even values.

Comment: Yes, but you should prove that it is true

Comment: @George can you give me any hints on how to do that?

Comment: An even integer can be written as $2$ times some number. Let $a=2k$. Now prove by induction that it is true for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. (Hint: look at part a)

Comment: @George part b of the question asks to explain so I'm not sure if they are looking for a full proof. How can I explain in words? Maybe my proof in part a helps me explain?

Comment: @George Could you please show me how to do part b?

Comment: Attempt to prove it by induction. If you haven't understood how to do it by now, you should probably review your knowledge on induction, or maybe check out some other examples.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(b)$ be the hypothesis that $2^{3b-1}+5.3^{b}$ is divisible by $11$ we shall show that $P(b) \Rightarrow P(b+2)$

Note that $64=55+9$ and
\begin{eqnarray*}
2^{3(\color{blue}{b+2})-1}+5 . 3^{\color{blue}{b+2}}= 2^{3b-1}.64+5.9.3^{b}=55.2^{3b-1}+9(\color{red}{2^{3b-1}+5.3^b})
\end{eqnarray*}
& the result follows from the inductive hypothesis.

For the second part, observe that for $b=1$, $2^{3b-1}+5.3^b=19$ and $b=2$ , $2^{3b-1}+5.3^b=77$. So it $P(b)$ true for all positive even values of $b$.

Comment: $11+45=56$, while $64=19+45$

Comment: @George ... thanks for pointing that out ... try this edit ?

Comment: What is the "inductive hypothesis" that you claim to be using?

Comment: @BillDubuque that the quantity in red is divisible by $11$ ... although it has not been decided, at this stage, weather $b$ is odd or even.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit What is your statement $P$ such that  $P(b)\,\Rightarrow\,P(b+1)?\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Sorry for not responding sooner (been busy at work). The hypothesis $P(b)$ is $2^{3b-1}+5.3^{b}$ is divisible by $11$ & the first equation shows $P(b) \Rightarrow P(b+2)$.

Comment: @Donald Thanks, you should make that explicit in your answer since it may not be clear to many readers.